# String erase() giving core dumped

Tags: c++, erase

I'm doing kata on codewars, and I need something like this:

When a letter in string occures two times - delete both.

I've done something like this:

```
    std::string str2 = str;

for(int i=0;i<str2.size();i++){
    for(int j=0;j<str2.size();j++){

        if(std::tolower(str2[i]) == std::tolower(str2[j]) && j != i){
            n++;
            str2.erase(str2.begin() + i);
            str2.erase(str2.begin() + j);

            i--;
            j--;
        }

    }
}
```

And getting core dumped ( it's caused by                 `str2.erase(str2.begin() + i);` ). I know it is somewhere my mistake with memory, but can You tell me what is wrong with this? I analyzed and didn't see anything bad there.

Comment: Take out a paper and pencil and try to figure out what happens when `i` is 3 and `j` is 5 and `str2.size()` is 6. The shown algorithm is fundamentally broken. Oh, and by the way if `i` is 5 and `j` is 3, don't think you're getting off scott-free. Both erase()s will work, but say "Hello" to undefined behavior on the next iteration of the inner loop.

Comment: `erase` potentially invalidates iterators. You don't account for that. == Kaboom!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Can I have a scot(t)ch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we can observe that when an erasure occurs we'll always have `i<j`.

#### Problem 1

Now if you delete the first char and then the second, you're shooting at a moving target: you need to adjust to the new position of the second char after having erased the first one:

```
        str2.erase(str2.begin() + i);
        str2.erase(str2.begin() + j-1);  // because former j c[j] is now c[j-1]
```

Another variant that is also suitable is to delete the second char first (doesn't change the position of the first):

```
        str2.erase(str2.begin() + j);   // because j> i it has no impact on i
        str2.erase(str2.begin() + i);
```

#### Optimisation 1

Unrelated, but we could also make use of our deduction on `i<j` to optimise or loop and save a significant number of useless comparisons:

```
for(int i=0;i<str2.size();i++) {
    for(int j=i+1;j<str2.size();j++) {
    ...
    }
}
```

#### Optimization 2

Another problem is that you perform `i--` in the inner loop, when `i` doesn't get incremented. This will have two consequences you will redo comparisons that you already do.  So just remove this decrement, and restart with `j=i+1`.

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/eXFjIT).

#### Problem 2 (left as an exercise)

Your algorithm does remove pairs of letters only.  So if you have more than 2 occurrences of a letter, only the two first will get removed. So you need to review your algorithm (attention to not erase several time the first occurence either ;-) )

Answer (score 1):

You're erasing two characters from `str2`.  If `i` is less than `j`, this can cause the second erase to access past the end of the string (and even if it isn't you'll be erasing the wrong character).